# Why does my list string removal function work for small lists, but not large ones?

Tags: python, list

Is there something I'm missing here? Kind of stumped on this problem. Hints are greatly appreciated!

Here is what my code is supposed to do:

> You are given a string of letters and an array of numbers.
> The numbers indicate positions of letters that must be removed, in order, starting from the beginning of the array.
> After each removal the size of the string decreases (there is no empty space).
> Return the only letter left.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> let str = "zbk", arr = [0, 1]
>     str = "bk", arr = [1]
>     str = "b", arr = []
>     return 'b'
> ```
>
> Notes
>
> - The given string will never be empty.
> - The length of the array is always one less than the length of the string.
> - All numbers are valid.
> - There can be duplicate letters and numbers.

Here is my code:

```
def last_survivor(letters, coords): 
    list1 = list(letters)
    for x in coords:
        for i in list1:
            if list1.index(i) == x:
                list1.remove(i)
    return print("".join(list1))
```

These function inputs work just fine and return expected output

```
last_survivor('abc', [1, 1])
last_survivor('kbc', [0, 1])    
last_survivor('zbk', [2, 1])
last_survivor('c', [])
last_survivor("abcdef", [1,2,1,1])
```

This very long function input does not return the desired output, 'b'

```
last_survivor('foiflxtpicahhkqjswjuyhmypkrdbwnmwbrrvdycqespfvdviucjoyvskltqaqirtjqulprjjoaiagobpftywabqjdmiofpsr', [8, 59, 52, 93, 21, 40, 88, 85, 59, 10, 82, 18, 74, 59, 51, 47, 75, 49, 23, 56, 1, 33, 39, 33, 34, 44, 25, 0, 51, 25, 36, 32, 57, 10, 57, 12, 51, 55, 24, 55, 31, 49, 6, 15, 10, 48, 27, 29, 38, 30, 35, 42, 23, 32, 9, 39, 39, 36, 8, 29, 2, 33, 14, 3, 13, 25, 9, 25, 18, 10, 1, 2, 20, 8, 2, 11, 5, 7, 0, 10, 10, 8, 12, 3, 5, 1, 7, 7, 5, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: `list1.index(i)` returns the index of the first occurrence of `i`. It won't do what you want if there are duplicate values in the list.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the length of the input. Your code doesn't work when there are duplicate letters.

Comment: And the instructions made it very clear about this: **There can be duplicate letters and numbers.**

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it

Answer (score 1):

`list1.index(i)` and `list1.remove(i)` find and remove the first occurrence of `i` in the list. This may not be the same index as `x` if there are duplicate letters in the string.

There's no need to use `index()` or `remove()`. You can remove an element by indext using the `pop()` method.

```
def last_survivor(letters, coords): 
    list1 = list(letters)
    for x in coords:
        list1.pop(x)
    return list1[0]
```

Also, your function is supposed to return the result, not print it. `return print(...)` makes the function return `None`, because `print()` doesn't return what it prints.

And since the conditions say that there will always be just one element left, you don't need to use `join()`, you can just return that element.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the clarification on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this, I just added a check to show you if you've given a wrong indeed in that long array. However it's better to do it with try and except method

```
def last_survivor(letters, coords): 
    list1 = list(letters)
    for x in coords:
        if (x < Len(list1)):
            list1.pop(x)
        else:
            print('provided index does not exist')
    return list1[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing and string concatenation to save all the string other than the single character at the edge of the two slices:

```
def last_survivor(s, cord):
    for e in cord:
        s=s[:e]+s[(e+1):]
    return s
```

Since it is slicing vs pop, there is no error if the coordinate is out of range or there are too many elements in the list of coordinates.